# Is there a preferred convention as to how key sequences are noted?

Tags: discussion, editing, answer-format, best-practice

Is there an unwritten convention that is considered more appropriate than others in reference to key sequence notation when replying to questions?  Specifically, which is considered more appropriate?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> <= All uppercase

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> <= mixed case lettering

I seem to recall the first methodology in a number of books I have had the opportunity to peruse over the years.  However, I see the latter methodology as matching the actual keys on a standard keyboard.

Comment: this is totally a bikeshed question, but since you asked :) I think proper casing is always easier to read, even in this context, than ALL CAPS SHOUTING

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Jeff, just pick one and move on. I prefer normal capitalisation too, but the discussion is not worth your time.

- [What do all CAPITAL letters typically refer to in writing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/what-do-all-capital-letters-typically-refer-to-in-writing/8678#8678)
- [Parkinson's Law of Triviality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The reason for asking the question has to do with the fact that I had been noticing a number of my responses being edited for this.  I was trying to get a feel for what the consensus was in an effort to reduce someone's effort editing.

Comment: I don't mind these edits, but if it's *the only* thing someone changes, it'll probably be rejected for being trivial.